# docker-compose gives SSL verification

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ssl-certificate

TLS based docker daemon is running on EC2 host.

docker client works fine with docker daemon, but `docker-compose` gives below error:

```
$ export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.31.3.2:2376 DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-2:~$ docker --tls image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hello-world         latest              fce289e99eb9        8 months ago        1.84kB

ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-2:~$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hello-world         latest              fce289e99eb9        8 months ago        1.84kB

ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-2:~$ docker-compose -f jenkinsDocker/docker-compose.yml  -p jenkins build
Building slavedotnet
ERROR: SSL error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.31.3.2', port=2376): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.21/build?q=False&pull=False&t=jenkins_slavedotnet&nocache=False&forcerm=False&rm=True (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:727)'),))
ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-2:~$
```

---

[here](https://github.com/stevebargelt/jenkinsDocker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) is yml file for `docker-compose` tool.

---

Why `docker-compose` does not connect to docker daemon? using TLS...

Comment: From a remote docker client am able to run `docker-compose`

Comment: From remote docker client, am able to launch docker containers on docker host(with public IP 35.18x.xxx.xxx).